# Remove dictionaries with identical values for a specific key considering another value in the dictionary in Python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a JSON file which is a list of dictionaries.

I want to remove the duplicate dicts based on the "book_id" key and keep just one of them with max value for the "id" key)

example:

```
book_list = [
{"id": 20, "user_id": 8, "device_id": 1, "book_id": 81},
{"id": 19, "user_id": 8, "device_id": 1, "book_id": 81},
{"id": 18, "user_id": 8, "device_id": 1, "book_id": 81},
{"id": 17, "user_id": 8, "device_id": 1, "book_id": 78},
{"id": 16, "user_id": 8, "device_id": 1, "book_id": 77},
{"id": 15, "user_id": 8, "device_id": 1, "book_id": 77},
{"id": 13, "user_id": 8, "device_id": 1, "book_id": 75}]
```

What I want is like that:

```
new_list = [
{'id': 20, 'user_id': 8, 'device_id': 1, 'book_id': 81},
{'id': 17, 'user_id': 8, 'device_id': 1, 'book_id': 78}, 
{'id': 16, 'user_id': 8, 'device_id': 1, 'book_id': 77}, 
{'id': 13, 'user_id': 8, 'device_id': 1, 'book_id': 75}]
```

executing the below code with this example list works completely well, and I got the desired result. but running on my JSON file data got some problems and cannot group them correctly
and it removes some of the duplicate values, but not all of them:

```
for key, value in groupby(book_list, key=lambda v: v["book_id"]):
            newlist.append(max(list(value), key=lambda v: v["id"]))
```

I try also this code, it can remove all the duplicate data but it gets the one with minimum id (it actually overwrite on the last dictionary):

```
    new_list = list({v['book_id']: v for v in book_list}.values())
```

I prefer lines of code that can be done in O(1) (if possible)

Comment: Why not keep a set of `book_id` as you encounter them and use that to filter them?

Answer (score 2):

try it:

```py
book_list = [
    {"id": 20, "user_id": 8, "device_id": 1, "book_id": 81},
    {"id": 19, "user_id": 8, "device_id": 1, "book_id": 81},
    {"id": 18, "user_id": 8, "device_id": 1, "book_id": 81},
    {"id": 17, "user_id": 8, "device_id": 1, "book_id": 78},
    {"id": 16, "user_id": 8, "device_id": 1, "book_id": 77},
    {"id": 15, "user_id": 8, "device_id": 1, "book_id": 77},
    {"id": 13, "user_id": 8, "device_id": 1, "book_id": 75}
]
new_book_list = [] 
_book_id_list = set() # ids added here # suggested by "MYousefi"

for book in book_list:
    if book['book_id'] not in _book_id_list:
        _book_id_list.add(book['book_id']) # dont accept a book Twice
        new_book_list.append(book)

print(f'{new_book_list = }')
```

thanks [MYousefi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1991397/myousefi)

Comment: Using a `set` is possibly better than using a list for `_book_id_list`. While `add` operation for both is `O(1)` the `in` operator on sets is typically `O(1)` while `O(n)` for lists.

Comment: The `=` in the print function would be a problem and will stick with an error.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks @Khayyam

Comment: @Khayyam
`print(f'{var = }') # var = <value>`

Comment: Oh wow :P. I didn't know that either. I will be so using that everywhere.

Comment: wouldn't work for me, tho. it'll result in `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` that refers to equal sign.

Comment: Probably a higher python 3.x version is required

Comment: Found it. Introduced in python 3.8. [self-documenting expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging)

Comment: Yea, I tried it in colab:) maybe that's why. But It'll be more valuable if any version could run it, tho. :] anyway , +1

Comment: @Delta, and MYousefi, Thanks a lot. Guys, you're the best :))
 I tried different ways and no one worked. Your solution just gave me my desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dict.setdefault` to create a dict of dict of lists. Loop over the values of outer dict and find max key of inner dict:

```
temp = {}
for d in book_list:
    temp.setdefault(d['book_id'], {}).setdefault(d['id'], []).append(d)
new_list = [v[max(v)] for v in temp.values()]
```

Output:

```
[[{'id': 20, 'user_id': 8, 'device_id': 1, 'book_id': 81}],
 [{'id': 17, 'user_id': 8, 'device_id': 1, 'book_id': 78}],
 [{'id': 16, 'user_id': 8, 'device_id': 1, 'book_id': 77}],
 [{'id': 13, 'user_id': 8, 'device_id': 1, 'book_id': 75}]]
```

Then again, looks like the list is already sorted, so we could reverse `book_list` and read the list, reverse it back:

```
new_list = list({d['book_id']: d for d in book_list[::-1]}.values())[::-1]
```

Comment: Many Thanks, @Enke. Your solution also worked. I cannot just vote it up. 
And thanks for editing my question too. The list is displayed much better now.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the list by 'id' and then form a temporary dictionary based on the 'book_id', only the dictionary with the largest id will be kept as value for each duplicate 'book_id' key:

```
ids = {b['book_id']:b for b in sorted(book_list,key=lambda b:b['id'])}
book_list = list(ids.values())

print(*book_list,sep='\n')
{'id': 13, 'user_id': 8, 'device_id': 1, 'book_id': 75}
{'id': 16, 'user_id': 8, 'device_id': 1, 'book_id': 77}
{'id': 17, 'user_id': 8, 'device_id': 1, 'book_id': 78}
{'id': 20, 'user_id': 8, 'device_id': 1, 'book_id': 81}
```